# How to reset that open vim with a clean window in mac's terminal

Tags: macos, vim, terminal

I encounted a problem after I change the syntax of mac's terminal vim. Right now, when I open vim, it just shows up under many line's of my shell command (screenshot below) instead of like before open a clean window and cannot see my shell command. So how can I reset it back that open my vim that in a clean terminal window?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally find out that because of the `TERM` is not set to xterm, so I fixed this issue by adding `export TERM=xterm-color` in my .bash_profile file. If you have the same issue, hope this would help.

Comment: You don't need to do that in your `.bash_profile`: there's an option in the preferences window for that.